# c: free() - glibc invalid pointer

Tags: c, malloc, free, glibc

I am writing a bit of code, in this case a function that sees if a piece of string is blank or not(as in, contains all space, tab or newlines or not). I can't seem to free the temp variable without running into an error.Here is the function:

```
int isBlank(char *a){

char *temp;
int blank = 1;
int position = 0;
if( a == NULL){
    return 1;
}

temp = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(a)+1);
strcpy(temp,a);
//printf("string: %s\n", temp);

while(*temp){
    if(*temp != ' ' && *temp != '\t' && *temp != '\n'){
        blank = 0;  
        break;

    }
    temp++;
}


    free(temp);

return blank;
```

}

I am traversing the string and comparing them to each of the spaces, but when I free temp, it gives me a glibc error

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000170e9f4 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
```

can anyone help me on this issue or point out what am I doing wrong here? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`temp++;` is executed (zero or more times) in the while loop, so the value of `temp` is probably modified.

You should store its original value in another pointer, and free that pointer.

```
temp = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(a)+1);
char *original_temp = temp;

while(*temp){
    // processing
    temp++;
}

free(original_temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

`temp++` makes the `temp` pointer point the next address. You should keep the original address of the array. Add this line before while loop:

```
char* original = temp;
```

and finally `free(original)` instead of `free(temp)`.